# Message that appears for a second and then dissapears Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Dumb question.  I am trying to get a message to appear and dissapear after a couple of seconds.  I just thought I would have a timeout function and at the end I would just append an empty string.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#resultDivSE').append('<b><p style="font:color:rgb(128,0,128)">' + data + '</p></b>');
}, 1000)
$('#resultDivSE').append('');
```

That doesn't appear to be working.  Am I missing something here... Also, How would you set the color of the text?

Comment: You want to use `.innerHTML`.

Comment: Are you expecting `$('#resultDivSE').append('');` to make it dissapear? You realize that line ADDS nothing, it doesn't REPLACE the content with nothing. To "append" is to add something onto the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is backwards.  You need to set the message right away and then, in the timeout, clear it.  To make a message appear for a second, you would do this:

```
$('#resultDivSE').html('<b><p style="color: #ff00ff">' + data + '</p></b>');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#resultDivSE').html("");
}, 1000);
```

P.S.  I've also filled in the proper style value for settings the color of the text.

P.P.S  One second is not a very long time for a message to display.  You probably want something like 5 seconds.

Comment: How did you get the right value for the color.  Forgive me but my Hex math is a little rusty.

Answer (score 3):

Append is ADDING a blank string to the end, you want to replace it, you want `.html('')`

for color you want `$('#resultDivSE').css('color' , '#FF0000')` (I think, I don't use jQuery much)

Comment: Wow... That was quick.  Thanks.  I should have figured I was doing something wrong here.  Thanks again.  Any recomendations on setting the color of the text?

Comment: $('#resultDivSE').style.color = "rgb(128,0,128)"; to set the colour.

Answer (score 1):

The append command adds text to the div you have selected.  To clear all the text in the div you would need:

```
$('#resultDivSE').html('');
```

To change the colour of the text in css you just use color: so your paragraph tag would look like this:

```
<p style="color:rgb(128,0,128)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html` instead of `.append`. Append will add something to your div, whereas `.html` will actually change the HTML.

Comment: @editor Esailija: What's wrong with .innerHTML compared to .html?

Answer (score 0):

Jquery css can help you set the color of the font:
http://api.jquery.com/css/
Use the css property of `Color`

It looks like you are missing a semi-colon at the end of your `setTimeout` string. Maybe I am just being clueless here, or am confused with the code snippet, but it seems like you are doing the opposite, and that the html you want appended to your result div will occur after the 1000 milliseconds.